# Does a restart of the service clears the MemoryCache?

Tags: c#, windows-services, memorycache

In C#, if my project's output is a window service and it uses MemoryCache, upon the restart of the service, will the MemoryCache be cleared?

Comment: It is stored in memory that's part of the process.  So there's no way for it to survive a restart of the process.  Of course, "restart" is vague for a service, it is still there when you stop and start it again.

Comment: "Of course, "restart" is vague for a service, it is still there when you stop and start it again." - now im confused

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be cleared, can't find a link online to support my answer but i'am 99% sure it does, try and create a scenario where you can test it.

Happy coding!